# Extract range of numbers in a list

Tags: r, list, numbers, extract

I want to select a part of a number in all the rows of a list

In the list I have a combination of numbers and letters like this but with more than 50000 rows:
E0091349
W0532050
E0085229
...
first I need to extract in a new list the first item (the letter), then the 3 first numbers in another list, other with the next 2 and finally other with the last 2.

I have already tried to use lapply or mapply but it's my first time with r studio and I'm still a bit lost

At the end I should have 4 list:
E0091349
W0532050
E0085229
...
1st list:
E
W
E
...
2nd list:
009
053
008
...
3rd list:
13 
20
52
...
4th list:
49
50
29
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `separate`, if you want to split the string at fixed location

```
tidyr::separate(df, col, paste0("V", 1:4), c(1, 4, 6, 8))

#  V1  V2 V3 V4
#1  E 009 13 49
#2  W 053 20 50
#3  E 008 52 29
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("E0091349", "W0532050", "E0085229"))
```

Comment: I defined the data like this: longitud_inicialsex<-select(segmentos,4)
As I need to extract previously some data to create the "longitud_inicialsex" table. Now to introduce that into the tidyr command should I do it like this?
tidyr::separate(longitud_inicialsex, paste("V", 1:4), c(1, 4, 6, 8)) an error appears: Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: you need to give a column name. What is the 4th column name? Try `tidyr::separate(longitud_inicialsex, column_name, paste("V", 1:4), c(1, 4, 6, 8))`

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution using `read.table`,

```
read.table(text = sub('(.{1})(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})', '\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4', d1$x),
              colClasses = rep('character', 4))
#  V1  V2 V3 V4
#1  E 009 13 49
#2  W 053 20 50
#3  E 008 52 29
```

**DATA:**

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(x = c("E0091349", "W0532050", "E0085229")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```